# The result of `difftime` is character, how can I get only number

Tags: r

The result of `difftime` is `Time difference of -1 days`, how can I only get `-1` ? (only want the number) . Thanks!

```
difftime(as.Date('2022-3-1'),as.Date('2022-3-2'),units=c("days"))
```

Comment: `as.numeric(difftime(as.Date('2022-3-1'),as.Date('2022-3-2'),units=c("days")))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.numeric()` to get a numeric vector with the time difference.

```r
as.numeric(difftime(as.Date('2022-3-1'),as.Date('2022-3-2'),units=c("days"))) 
#> [1] -1
```

This will get you a numeric vector:

```r
str(as.numeric(difftime(as.Date('2022-3-1'),as.Date('2022-3-2'),units=c("days"))))
#>  num -1
```

You might want to have a look at `?difftime`, it gives a nice overview on how difftime object can be used. `?as.numeric` also provides complementary information.